# Why 1[''] evaluates to undefined, but 1[] throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ']`

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

How is Javascript interpreting the expression `1['']` as `undefined`, yet `1[]` throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ']`?

```js
console.log(1[''])
```

```js
console.log(1[])
```

Comment: I'd guess `1['']` tries to get the property called `''` from `1`, while the other is just invalid.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine I'm confused as to why `1` isn't rejected as an invalid variable identifier

Comment: Because `1` is an instance of `number`

Comment: Because if you want to access an object's property  with `[]` notation, you have to provide a name. Your second example doesn't to that, thus it's a synax error. Your first example provides an empty string as name, there is no such property, thus the result is `undefined`

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine aha, so `1` is being treated as a number object, that makes sense

Comment: It's called "autoboxing" if you want to google for more info.

Comment: @AndrewParks Yeah, just try `1["toFixed"](3)`, you'll get `"1.000"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subscript operator (`[]`) is used to access an object's properties.

`1` is a number literal, which is evaluated as a Number object when followed by `['objectPropertyName']`. It does not have a property `''`, and thus returns `undefined` when you call `1['']`.

`1[]`, on the other hand, is just a syntax error - you can't omit the property you're trying to access. In other words, you have to have *something* in the braces.